# Display a button or add sound on javascript stop function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have `divs` that are draggable. When a div is stopped being dragged by the user, how do I display a confirm button and play some background sound "Are you sure"? Also, if the user starts dragging the div again, confirm button opacity should be decreased. So on clicking the confirm button, `'$get('ajax/update_position.php'` should be activated.

```
function make_draggable(elements)
{
    /* Elements is a jquery object: */

    elements.draggable({
        containment:'parent',
        start:function(e,ui){ ui.helper.css('z-index',++zIndex); },
        stop:function(e,ui){

            /* Sending the z-index and positon of the note to update_position.php via AJAX GET: */

            $.get('ajax/update_position.php',{
                  x     : ui.position.left,
                  y     : ui.position.top,
                  z     : zIndex,
                  id    : parseInt(ui.helper.find('span.data').html())
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your requirements correctly:

<sub>Irrelevant code commented out to not break JSFiddle</sub>

```
var $button = $("button"); 

function make_draggable(elements) {
    /* Elements is a jquery object: */

    elements.draggable({
        containment: 'parent',
        start: function (e, ui) {
            /*ui.helper.css('z-index', ++zIndex);*/
            // if the user starts dragging the div again, confirm button opacity should be decreased
            $button.hide(1000); // meaning hide the button
        },
        stop: function (e, ui) {
            // When a div is stopped being dragged by the user, how do I display a confirm button and play some background sound "Are you sure"? 

            $button.show(1000);  // display button

            /*Add code to play music here*/
        }
    });
}

$button.click(function () {
    alert(1); // check to make sure function is called
    /* Sending the z-index and positon of the note to update_position.php via AJAX GET: */
    /* removed to not disturb jsfiddle
            $.get('ajax/update_position.php',{
                  x     : ui.position.left,
                  y     : ui.position.top,
                  z     : zIndex,
                  id    : parseInt(ui.helper.find('span.data').html())
            });           */
});

make_draggable($("div"));
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/4y94E/1/)

Comment: On document load, the button should not be visible. Only when they start dragging the draggable divs and stop it, it should show up. But yes. Overall this is what I wanted.

Comment: @Venky Glad it did :)

Comment: Ajax call is not happening.

Comment: @Venky I had commented it out. Make sure there's no syntax error. And it won't work on JSFiddle.

Comment: @Venky Might be that `zIndex` is not defined there.

Comment: Yes. I removed the comment and checked if there is any syntax error. It still not working

Comment: I checked that too. Developer's tool on chrome is not showing anything regarding z-index

Comment: @Venky Sorry, but I do not know where do I test it. In JSFiddle, I get errors like `ui` undefined. Perhaps, I think this problem is out of the scope of this question. You can check that the function for `onclick` of button is fired by that `alert(1)`. So there's definitely something else causing the issue. And hence, I think you should, thus, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @Venky Though if you could provide means to test, that would be great.

Comment: I think `$button.click(function ()` is not working. because when I click confirm, it is not popping up the alert box.

Comment: Javascript console is now giving "Cannot read property 'position' of undefined"( which is ui.position). I guess this is because we have written `$.get('ajax/update_position.php'` in a separate function under which `ui` is not defined.

Comment: @Venky I can give a last try to use `opacity` http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/4y94E/4/ . It's strange why the `alert` doesn't work for you. It is working fine for me.

Comment: That's strange ! But wait, you need to set a default `opacity:0`, and I see you haven't done that. Set it and tell the status.

Comment: I have set `opcacity` to 0. It is not showing up even after moving some div

Comment: Last of all: I can only tell to use `$("button")` in place of `$button`, but I am sorry I have ran out of ideas. What puzzles me is that the same code works on JSFiddle, but it doesn't work on the page. My Personal Advice: Please use http://www.jsbeautifier.org to make your JS code look clean. It makes debugging much easier.